# Windows 10 shutting off USB drives

Tags: windows-10, usb, power-management

I have a Windows 10 laptop, running Windows 10 Home.   It keeps shutting off USB drive, while the drive is actively being written to.  I get about an hour before it shuts down the drive.  Again, this happens while I am writing to the drive, and I suddenly get write errors.  I thought it was power management, but maybe it's something else?

I've gone into device management, USB root hubs, and turned off power management on all root hubs.

I've gone into power management, USB management, and disabled power management.
I've rebooted.

It's still happening.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Are we talking about a single USB device or multiple different devices?

Comment: Flash drive could be overheating. External HDD: use a third-party tool. See https://alternativeto.net/software/keepalivehd/

Comment: Are you sure the write errors are because the drive shuts down, and not the opposite way around? For example, an unnecessarily long USB 3 cable can itself cause the device to reset due to unstable connection.